# Homebrew, Python not installing as expected

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

So I've installed homebrew correctly, and just installed python using the simple brew install python command on my Mac OSX running 10.11.6

However, when i run "which python" the output is //anaconda/bin/python... this makes some sense as I've been using the anaconda navigator for my python code in my econometrics class.. but I wanted it to install as expected in usr/local/bin/python like it is in these instructions: https://penandpants.com/2012/02/24/install-python/ . any idea on what to do, i've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling homebrew, and the same thing happens. So if there is an easy way to uninstall the python package, then reinstall it correctly would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Do you set a PATH in your .bash_profile or .bashrc?  Type `echo $PATH` at a Terminal -- is the anaconda folder there?

Comment: You have (at least) two different interpreters on your machine. `python` is currently resolving to the python at `//anaconda/bin/python...`. This can probably be resolved by fixing PATH.

Comment: @LouFranco yep, here's the output //anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin

Comment: Yup, the anaconda path is being checked first, and the `python` binary is being run form that path.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what do you mean by fixing the path, do i need to uninstall anything first?

Comment: @bobsaget123 No. The PATH variable is just a list of paths that are checked when you use `something`, if `something` is found, then it is run. So, most of the binaries will typically be in some directory called "bin". For example, your PATH variable includes `/usr/local/‌​bin`. Try `ls /usr/local/bin` and you will see a bunch of binaries you are probably using. One quick, although dirty, solution is to use use `export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions‌​/3.6/bin:$PATH"` at the bottom of your `~/.bash_profile` and then either open a new terminal or `source .bash_profile`.

Comment: The problem is, if you look in your `.bash_profile`, that anaconda automatically adds `export PATH="/Users/juan/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"` to it, *prepending* the anaconda `bin`, so it is always checked first. You could also just comment out that line.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh okay that makes sense, is this issue something i should be worried about or is it not really gonna give me any trouble

Comment: Well, if you just comment out that line, it will just prevent you from using the anaconda distribution with `python` in the terminal. Shouldn't be a big deal.